# App Store submission April 2020 Requirement and using some below swift 5 third party library on carthage

Tags: swift, swift5, carthage

Based on question from -> [iOS April 2020 Requirements -- iOS 13 SDK, All-Screen Design, Launch Storyboard, Swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58951761/ios-april-2020-requirements-ios-13-sdk-all-screen-design-launch-storyboard/60726113#60726113)

I'm interested in confirming a few things regarding question number 1

> Does this requirement force developers to use Swift 5? we have a
>   couple huge Swift 3 projects with many third-party dependencies. It's
>   a hassle to update those projects to Swift 5.

If the project itself runs on Swift 5 but using a carthage library that some of it runs below Swift 5, will App Store accept the app submission ?

Comment: No, Xcode 11 doesn't support compiling, Migrating, or running Swift 3.X code. Xcode will tell you you need at least Xcode 10.1 to migrate/compile Swift 3.X, Apple does allow you to upload your apps using Xcode 10.1. However, your time is limited so I advise you to start migrating to at least Swift 4

Comment: Just to make sure, by updating third party library that support at least swift 4 while the project itself runs on swift 5 will be accepted by app store? @jbiser361

Comment: What I think, you need to use xcode 11. Apple has to accept all the apps which are uploaded from xcode11. So any code which can be compiled by xcode 11 is good to go

Comment: Yes, I'm just beginning to understand that as long as the project compiles on Xcode 11 and making sure not using UIWebView as it has been deprecated is good to go :)